# WPF from ICommand back to MainView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm probably missing the point here, I've been digging around for some time now, looked at [the different approaches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx) to bind views and view models and how to navigate between them.

**Setup:**

- 1 MainWindow (ViewModel: `MainWindowViewModel`)
- MainWindow contains some visuals and a `ContentControl` that is binded to a `ViewModelBase`. So in `MainWindowViewModel` I can set any other view(model) to display.
- Got two user controls, one is a login form, the other one is for now a loading indicator.

Inside App.xaml

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:LoginViewModel}">
   <Views:LoginView />
    </DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:LoadingViewModel}">
        <Views:LoadingView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Goal:**
From the ICommand inside `LoginViewModel` go back to the `MainWindowViewModel`, a long with the form data. `MainWindowViewModel` will then switch to `LoadingViewModel`, do async call to a service. Next time on startup when a refresh token is saved, I will show the `LoadingViewModel` instead of the login form. On completion a new window will open (or something else, don't know yet).

**Problem:** Most examples show how to do it when a button is outside of both User Controls, so when the ICommand is inside the MainWindow, then it would be easy, yet the event is called from one of the subviews. Using PropertyChange seems a bit off as well.

Let's dig into some code, shell we?

MainWindow.xaml, only one important line

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs, in constructor

```
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

MainWindowViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ViewModelBase CurrentView { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CurrentView = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DelegateCommand loginCommand { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute);
    }

    private bool CanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        //I need to go to MainWindowViewModel
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    //more properties below heere.
```

`ViewModelBase` inherits from `BindableBase` (from Prism), so that handles the PropertyChanged events. The properties inside my view models use the correct `SetProperty` methods. *I prefer not to use Prism's region, IEventAggregator or Unitiy.*

**Solutions**

What comes to mind is sending an interface a long with the constructor, and use the interface to do 'callbacks' to the `MainWindowViewModel`, but I guess this will give errors, since I will change the view, and thus setting `MainWindowViewModel.CurrentView` to something else, leaving `LoginViewModel` null. Since the request is coming from that object I can imagine it is not really good.

Comment: How about handling all this in the getter and setter of your ´ViewModelBase´. This is the only place where you will have both old and new values at the same time at your diaposal.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. No ViewModel should know anything about Views. The whole idea is that your Views and ViewModels should be totally separated, and you should be able to totally change your View or ViewModel, and it still should work.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Yes, I know. That is why I keep the 3 view models separate. I don't see that I am doing anything off MVVM here, until now it's just basic implementation. And sometimes there are requirements that make it a little less MVVM, perhaps this is one of them but I am looking for a solution that best suits MVVM and of course solid code. XAMIMAX: Uhhm, these are 2 different instances and I don't really need the old and new values.

Comment: Looks like perfectly fine MVVM to me. I use callbacks myself, but I use a dependency injection framework (Ninject) to more easily facilitate unit testing. It's not very clear though why you think this is potentially problematic, if you've set the CurrentView to something else then why would the old view ever call the callback?

Comment: Because the flow I have in mind is `LoginViewModel.someCommand` -> `callbackInterface.SomeMethod` -> `MainWindowViewModel.SomeMethod` (that implements the interface). -> Set `CurrentView` to `LoadViewModel`. Because I first had `LoginViewModel` as CurrentView, I am overriding it, seems to me that it will be null then. But I guess I will have the other view models as separate fields and set a reference to that in CurrentView. Not entirely happy with this implementation though.

Comment: What I meant with doing it wrong was because you somehow keep your views in your viewmodels. ViewModels should not know anything about the views. I would instead keep a reference to the viewmodel and somehow in the XAML show the correct View. That way when you are creating your LoginViewModel, you can in the contructor reference your MainViewModel. That you way you will have access to your MainViewModel from you LoginViewModel.

Comment: What I meant is to handle your login command from the transition but nevermind if i start explaining i will lose all of the characters fro comments. However if you want to call the `LoginCommand` from `MainViewModel` then use event handlers. When you create your `LoginViewModel` subscribe to an event called `OnLogin` then the handler if the command was a success could change the `BaseViewModel` Property with appropriate values, and you can always create these dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to communicate is the Messanger (MVVM Light) or EventAggregator (Prism) concept.

It's basically an in memory pub/sub system.

Here is an example from an article on MSDN

[MVVM - Messenger and View Services in MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx)

[Using the event aggregator pattern to communicate between view models](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/)

I am not sure which framework/library are you using but most MVVM framework have a similar concept for lousily coupled communication.

This is a very powerful concept for handling communication. But with great power comes responsibility =)...

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I know the concept, I mentioned in my question that I rather not use it. I didn't look at MVVM Light, but i don't like the way Prism wants you to fill up your constructor with an eventAggregator. Perhaps I will use it for other scenarios later.